# Sublime 3 - Set Key map for function Goto Definition

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I want to create an Eclipse style shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MouseClick</kbd> to open the function/method. Sublime Text 3 has already this function called `goto_definition` but it is bound to <kbd>F12</kbd>.

[image]

But I'm not sure how to create this binding. I looked [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/vintage.html) for documentation but it was too complex. Can you one help me out with this simple key binding?

**Edit:** Following this article I was told to do this: [http://webtempest.com/better-definition-navigation-in-sublime-text-3/](http://web.archive.org/web/20130511063525/http://webtempest.com/better-definition-navigation-in-sublime-text-3)

```
[
    {
        "button": "button1", 
        "count": 1, 
        "modifiers": ["super", "shift"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "command": "goto_definition"
    }
]
```

This doesn't seem to work, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> executes nothing.

Comment: `super` is the windows key for Windows and Linux and the command key for OS X, not control. Try that and see if you get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

For anyone else who wants to set Eclipse style goto definition, you need to create `.sublime-mousemap` file in Sublime `User` folder.

Windows - create `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap` in `%appdata%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User`

Linux - create `Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap` in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User`

Mac - create `Default (OSX).sublime-mousemap` in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User`

Now open that file and put the following configuration inside

```json
[
    {
        "button": "button1", 
        "count": 1, 
        "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "command": "goto_definition"
    }
]
```

You can change `modifiers` key as you like.

---

Since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-`button1` on Windows and Linux is used for multiple selections, adding a second modifier key like <kbd>Alt</kbd> might be a good idea if you want to use both features:

```json
[
    {
        "button": "button1", 
        "count": 1, 
        "modifiers": ["ctrl", "alt"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "command": "goto_definition"
    }
]
```

Alternatively, you could use the right mouse button (`button2`) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> alone, and not interfere with any built-in functions.

Comment: This seems like the correct answer, but i did everything you said and still It not working i'm `ctrl` + `click` and its not doing anything, I get an error `Unable to parse binding`

Comment: have you checked configuration file name? can you post error screenshot somewhere?

Comment: Does anyone know how you'd right click for this? I was able to add to a Context.sublime-menu file the command but couldn't figure out how to pass in the args for the currently selected text...Or line...I searched for a good while trying to find documentation (and did try "args": "drag_select") but couldn't figure it out. I'd rather right click and jump to definition though this does work great! Thanks.

Comment: Could I also bind the enter key to this so I don't have to manually press it everytime i ctrl + click?

Comment: @BorisSamardžija , also how do i make the above script look for the function definition in my current file rather than jumping to other external files.

Answer (score 94):

To set go to definition to alt + d. From the Menu Preferences > Key Bindings-User. And then add the following JSON.

```
[
    { "keys": ["alt+d"], "command": "goto_definition" }
]
```

Comment: Not certain why I got down voted but this solution is working perfectly for me on Sublime 3.

Comment: You probably got downvoted because the original question asked "I want to create a Eclipse style shorcut Ctrl+MouseClick to open the function/method". I found your answer useful inasmuch as I'm not interested in the mouse shortcut version, so I've upvoted. :)

Comment: seems like better option than the cmd+opt+down

Comment: Possible to use `button1` instead of `d`... so, we have like `"alt" + "button"`

Answer (score 23):

If you want to see how to do a proper definition go into Sublime Text->Preferences->Key Bindings - Default and search for the command you want to override.

```
{ "keys": ["f12"], "command": "goto_definition" },
{ "keys": ["super+alt+down"], "command": "goto_definition" }
```

Those are two that show in my Default.

On Mac I copied the second to override.

in Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Key Bindings - User I added this

```
/* Beginning of File */

[
    {
        "keys": ["super+shift+i"], "command": "goto_definition" 
    }
]

/* End of File */
```

This binds it to the Command + Shift + 1 combination on mac.

Answer (score 8):

On a mac you have to set keybinding yourself.  Simply go to

```
Sublime --> Preference --> Key Binding - User
```

and input the following:

```
{ "keys": ["shift+command+m"], "command": "goto_definition" }
```

This will enable keybinding of `Shift + Command + M` to enable goto definition. You can set the keybinding to anything you would like of course.

Comment: On linux & windows change `shift+command+m` to `shift+control+m`

Answer (score 4):

ctrl != super on windows and linux machines.

If the F12 version of "Goto Definition" produces results of several files, the "ctrl + shift + click" version might not work well. I found that bug when viewing golang project with GoSublime package.

Comment: CMD+SHIFT+MOUSE1 does not work!
what the right sintax to make click on con GoTo Definition?

Comment: @Magico Required GoSublime install and it may only work for Golang project. [GoSublime: Godoc/Goto Definition](https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime/blob/master/USAGE.md#godocgoto-definition) `ctrl+dot,ctrl+g` or `ctrl+shift+left-click` on Windows. Replace ctrl as command on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Sublime portable version (for Windows) and this (placing the mousemap in `SublimeText\Packages\User` folder) did not work for me.

I had to place the mousemap file in `SublimeText\Data\Packages\User` folder to get it to work where `SublimeText` is the installation directory for my portable version.  `Data\Packages\User` is where I found the keymap file as well.

Answer (score 0):

One should not *just* configure the `goto_definition` shortcut -- you would also need a shortcut to go back(and forth) after you jump to the definition.

Hence, consider configuring *all three* shortcuts: `goto_definition`, `jump_back`, and `jump_forward` as follows in your **Key Bindings** config file :

```json
// go to the definition
{ "keys": ["ctrl+i"], "command": "goto_definition" },
// go back to the previous location
{ "keys": ["ctrl+h"], "command": "jump_back" },
// go to the next location
{ "keys": ["ctrl+l"], "command": "jump_forward" },
```

I find these three commands especially useful while trying to read code quickly.