# Edit the key map for goto definition

Tags: sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, sublimetext3

According to this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235706/sublime-3-set-key-map-for-function-goto-definition), I added this :

```
[
    {
        "button": "button1", 
        "count": 1, 
        "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "command": "goto_definition"
    }
]
```

To a file which a named `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap` in `%appdata%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User` .And it works just fine. The only issue here is that the mutiselection feature of sublime text not to work, so I thought I could edit this in such to maintain the multiselection `(ctrl + alt + click) or (ctrl + shift + click)`  :

```
[
    {
        "button": "button1", 
        "count": 1, 
        "modifiers": ["ctrl + alt"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "command": "goto_definition"
    }
]
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any help with this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting it to the following:

```json
[
    {
        "button": "button1", 
        "count": 1, 
        "modifiers": ["ctrl", "alt"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "command": "goto_definition"
    }
]
```

The `"modifiers"` array needs to have the individual keys as individual values, separated by commas - `["ctrl", "alt"]`, instead of having them both together concatenated with a plus `+`. This is one of the differences between keymaps and mousemaps.

Comment: FYI, I edited the answer in your linked question to clarify this.