# Linux Utility to `Go to definition`s

Tags: linux, development-environment

I'm starting to develop a fairly large app and am beginning to want some of the IDE features I've used in the past, such as 'right-click->go to definition' of a function.  Does any kind of parallel in developing on the command line exist?  This is on an Ubuntu Desktop VM.  Is recommended to move to using [Sublime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235706/sublime-3-set-key-map-for-function-goto-definition)?

Comment: Can you be a bit  more specific? What programming language? What do you want to develop? What did you use in the past? There are IDEs like Eclipse, KDevelop, Netbeans, there are powerful editors like Emacs, vim, Kate which can provide you some IDE features.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your preferred editor, but options definitely exist.

I've used [c-tags for vim](http://andrew.stwrt.ca/posts/vim-ctags/).
Similar options must exist for emacs; a quick search turned [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags) up.

In my experience though, nothing beats a full-fledged IDE (more full-fledged than Sublime, even) for these kinds of introspective utilities.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using VIM, check [VIM Taglist](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) plugin. It has a command that takes you to a `ctag` definition.

You can create a VIM keymap to go to the word/function under the cursor which would solve your problem.