# is there any sublime plugin that can jump to component page when click component name in React as vscode?

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

is there any sublime plugin that can jump to component page when click component name in React as vscode?
i try to search it, but not find.
it is different with `goto_definition` of function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime 3 - Set Key map for function Goto Definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235706/sublime-3-set-key-map-for-function-goto-definition)

Comment: @VivekDoshi no,it is a different question, sublime 'Goto Definition' is for function, not work for React Component.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)